# ldap auth with php fails intermittently

Tags: php, apache, active-directory, ldap

I have put together a basic web-app, the actual web-app itself works fine. However I wanted to add user authentication using our existing ldap server. The ldap script seems to work intermittently though, when logging in the first few attempts will fail with the 'access denied' message then it will authenticate. I ran the script stand alone without the app and the same behavior applies.

I cant seem to tie the problem down anywhere, I can only assume it is occuring on the ldap side and not the php side. I have included the script below, any help would be great.

While writing this, it failed to auth 3 times and passed twice...

```
<?php

$user = $_POST['login-name'];
$password = $_POST['login-pass'];

$ldap_user = 'uid='.$user.',ou=people,dc=ourdomain,dc=com,dc=au';
$ldap_pwd = $password;

$ldaphost = 'ldap://ldapserver.domain.com';
$ldapport = 389;

$ds = ldap_connect($ldaphost, $ldapport)
or die("Could not connect to $ldaphost");
if ($ds)
{
    $username = $ldap_user;
    $upasswd = $password;

    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ds, $username, $upasswd);


    if ($ldapbind)
        {
            //print "Congratulations! $username is authenticated.";
            header('Location: message.html');
        }
    else
        {print "Access Denied!";}


}
?>
```

Comment: Do you get an "Access Denied" or a "Could not connect to $ldaphost" when it fails? Are you always using the same user with the same credentials? Can you add a call to ```ldap_error()``` in the ```else```-block?

Comment: ```ldap_connect``` does **not** connect but only checks whether the provided  URI or FQDN or IP-Address makes sense! You should **not** rely on it's result to check whether the server is actually reachable!

Comment: @heiglandreas - I get Access Denied, have never got 'Could not connect'. I have tried with various user credentials and the same results always occur. I can certainly add ldap_error() to the else block. Is their a better alternative to using ldap_connect?

Comment: There is no other way than usin ldap_connect. It checks whether the URI or address of the ldap-server makes sense and returns a connection handle. It's a missleading naming as the actual connection will not be initiated until the first ldap_bind. Therefore connection issues will occur on that ldap_bind, **not** on ldap_connect.

Comment: So when you test with "user 1" you'll always be able to connect but with "user2" theres never a connection possible? Or regardless which user you try it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't?

Comment: Regardless of the user - sometimes it works and sometimes it doesnt. Same outcome affects any user that attempts to authenticate.

Comment: any news from the ```ldap_error()```- output?

Comment: Yup - it reports 'protocol error' when access is denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should set the LDAP-protocol version to 3 using

```
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
```

before calling `ldap_bind()`.

I've found this at http://php.net/manual/de/function.ldap-bind.php#72795

Comment: Yep spot on! I did a quick google from the ldap_error() and saw particularly with OpenLDAP you have to specify the version. Its working as expected now, thanks very much for your help!